# Table view inside a scroll view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, constraints

Below you can see my hierarchy of items in a storyboard. The problem is that the content size is shrinked and equals to the scroll view height. I suppose that happens because storyboard forces me to explicitly specify table view's height that I should not do. But how should I indicate dynamic height of a content view?

[image]

The list of constraints:

[image]

I know that there are several topics considering the same question, but methods which were given there don't help actually.

Comment: Is your table view a fixed size? Static content... never changes?

Comment: Why you use UITableView inside UIScrollView? try this: Drag and drop UIView into UITableView, its work as header of table view. And add static controls (in your case UILabel and Header collection.) into view.

Comment: @DonMag no, content is depended on core data, so i can't explicitly specify its height.

Comment: @KirillKorolev - OK, then trying to put a vertically-scrolling table view inside a vertically-scrolling scroll view is a bad idea. As JD says... get rid of the scroll view and just use a table view (or a collection view). Put your Label and collection view into the table header - or even create additional Cell classes for them. In general, it's best to use the Objects as they are intended to be used when you can (which is true in your case).

Comment: I have the same situation here and fixed it by using header, footer and sections. But it is a lot of work and more complex to maintain. For example, actions need extra work like adding custom cells with delegates to react on button press. Did you find a solution, if yes, can you share it with us?